# Custom directive from jQuery not loaded correctly

Tags: angularjs, directive

I am trying to load -outside angular -  dynamically a custom directive 
but the custom directive is not loaded in spite I have used `$compile` 
as the following : 
the custom directive is :

```
app.directive('mydirective',function (){
  return {
     template: '<div>Succeeded !</div>',
  }
})
```

and here the place I am loading dynamically the directive :

```
function showresultcust() {
angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();
        var _html = '<div>{{name}}-</div><div mydirective >Not Succeed</div>';
        //var _html='<div >{{loaded}}</div>';
        var obj = $('#content');
        $('#content').html($compile(_html)(scope));
        // compile!!!
        $compile(obj.contents())(scope);
        scope.$digest();
        setTimeout(function () {
            scope.$apply();
        });
    }
]);
}
```

Please note that `{{name}}` in the dynamic HTML is loaded correctly, but not the custom directive.
The full demo is in [this 'plnkr.co' link](https://plnkr.co/edit/8fktZPAi7sAz69VtwTC6?p=preview)

If you could do the correction directly in the 'plnkr' link above, I would appreciate that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is not compiling the `mydirective` directive because it is not part of the `ng` module. Add the module that contains the directive to the dependency list of the new injector.

```
//NOT this   
//angular.injector(['ng']).invoke(['$compile',

//Do this
angular.injector(['ng','tumblr']).invoke(['$compile',
    function ($compile) {
        var scope = angular.element(document.getElementById("test1")).scope();
        var _html='<div>{{name}}-</div><div mydirective >Not Succeed</div>';
        $('#content').html($compile(_html)(scope));
        scope.$apply();
    }
]);
}
```

The `angular.injector` function always creates a new injector and it needs all of the dependencies in the dependency list.

Comment: It works ! Thanks @georgeawg i have just changed the tumblr to the actual name plunker

Comment: One more question please , when I use templateUrl it is again not translating the template it is showing {{name}} , and it is only when load dynamically with the same way but using templateUrl here the example  : http://plnkr.co/edit/L82o3zVbM5p76Kyfp8WE?p=preview

Comment: Notice in my example the simplified the compile and apply. Your plnkr has two `$compile`s and a raw `setTimeout`. All that stuff in unnecessary.

Comment: thanks @georgeawg  , I will update it , and can you please help why if I use templateUrl demo here :plnkr.co/edit/L82o3zVbM5p76Kyfp8WE?p=preview  is not translated correctly ?